# Auto Sizing c# WPF windows anything smaller it goes off the screen

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, autosize

I am trying to set the WPF window to resize depending on the resolution however, I cannot seem to get it right. Does anyone have any suggestions or articles I should read to achieve this?

I have included some sample code that i have tried as a base to work off.

This code works fine at 1920 by 1080 but anything smaller it goes off the screen

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

```xml
<WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,-21" RenderTransformOrigin="0.0,0.0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="100" Margin="0,30,-400,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Source="G:\Pi Project\Project Pi Logo.png" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Label Content="The Pi Project" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="60" Margin="0,132,-390,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Button x:Name="saveProject_btn" Content=" Save&#xD;&#xA;Project" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="200" Margin="0,815,-415,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FontFamily="OCR A Extended" FontSize="36" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="home_btn" Content="Return&#xD;&#xA; Home" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="200" Margin="0,600,-415,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" FontFamily="OCR A Extended" FontSize="36" Click="home_btn_Click"/>
        <Label x:Name="projectCodeViewer" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="560" Margin="50,455,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1425" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" BorderBrush="Black" FontSize="36" FontFamily="OCR A Extended" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="MoveCommands_LB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="289" Margin="50,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="648" SelectionChanged="Movement_List_Populate" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <ListBox x:Name="Values_LB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="289" Margin="735,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328"/>
        <Button Content="Add Command" HorizontalAlignment="left" Height="289" Margin="1100,30,-53,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="428" FontSize="48"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I think the biggest problem is that you are setting Height and Width directly on the controls.  This prevents WPF from auto scaling.  Have you tried not setting explicit values for these attributes and checked out the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XAML if you want to automatically position any kind of Object on your window it is highly discouraged (in my point of view) to set margins that could make your Objects go out of bounds.

You also have to think where you want to position them and how they should react when you resize them, for example, if you have a header that's supposed to use the entire `Width` of the Parent control (in this case Window), then it should have no `Width`, `HorizontalAlignment` set to `Stretch` and no `Margins` (except if you want to make it have a free space from all sides)

Another example would be a Button that is used to close your Window, the best practice would be to actually place it on the bottom right with `HorizontalAlignment` set to `Right` and `VerticalAlignment` set to `Bottom` with no Margins, except like above, you want to make it have some padding off the corners.

That way when you resize everything flows perfectly to the places relative to the size of the Window, keeping the same proportions, here an example of what I explained above:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Header" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Height="50" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Beige"/>
    <!-- Inside this Grid we insert the Body -->
    <Grid Margin="5,55,5,60" Background="LightGray" >
        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect />
        </Grid.Effect>
        <Label Content="Hello World!" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" />
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Exit" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" Width="100" Margin="0,0,5,5" />
</Grid>
```

What I did above is still not how you could resolve it the best way, because I'm setting Margins and not defining a "set structure", for that the `Grid` object has a great feature, `ColumnDefinitions` and `RowDefinitions`, below is the same code but with those definitions that help me define sections in my XAML structure:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Header" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Height="50" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Beige"/>
    <!-- Inside this Grid we insert the Body -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,5,10" Background="LightGray" >
        <Grid.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect />
        </Grid.Effect>
        <Label Content="Hello World!" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" />
    </Grid>
    <Button Content="Exit" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" Width="100" Margin="0,0,5,5" />
</Grid>
```

So all you gotta do is actually structure that Resizable layout you're making like I did and you're set.

Comment: Great seems to make sense but just to clarify, every object inside the grid should be allocated a `grid.row"Some_int"` or `Grid.Column"some_int"` Value is that correct? Then inside each of these the desired min size of the object can be determined?

Comment: You can set the MinHeight Property of your RowDefinition if you don't want that certain row to be smaller than Y, and the same goes for ColumnDefinition by setting the MinWidtht Property if you don't want it to be smaller than X.

Comment: Also, the Default value of every object Grid.Column/Grid.Row is 0, so if you want an Object to be in X0,Y0, you don't need to set those, but I still do it to make it easier to read, that way I instantly know that said Object is inside that Grid in a Row or Column.

Comment: if you want it to take further, you can also apply MinWidth and MinHeight to the Objects that are inside your Grid, for example <Button Height="50" MinHeight="30"/>

Comment: Great! thanks for explaining that, getting to grips with it now.